# Umbraco examine indexes management tool

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7, examine

I'm looking for a tool to manage umbraco examine.
I need to view/edit/change/delete the indexes (and more..)
I tried to use Luke but is too old and very complicated ...

Does anyone know of a newer tool and easy to use?
(Preferably free)

Answer (score 3):

Luke is perfect for testing your queries (using a variety of options, my favourite being the RAW Lucene Query).

You could use the built-in Examine Management Dashboard to view your indexes, and test your queries also.

The Dashboard allows you to view:
- Total Nodes indexed
- NodeTypes Included/Excluded
- All System & User fields that are currently being indexed based off your configuration.
- Test Searching on your indexes (Text based or Lucene search)

Further Reading:
https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/reference/searching/examine/

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is **Marple**:

https://github.com/flaxsearch/marple

This offers a more 'modern' option than Luke, offering a browser-based UI using a Java back-end and a React front-end.